# Making POST request in Go with formdata and authentication

Tags: go

I'm currently trying to interface with an OAuth api with the example curl command `curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -d grant_type=client_credentials https://us.battle.net/oauth/token`. My current go file is:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
)

func checkErr(err error) bool {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return true
}

func authcode(id string, secret string, cli http.Client) string {
    //un(trace("authcode"))
    var form bytes.Buffer
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&form)
    _, err := w.CreateFormField("grant_type=client_credentials")
    checkErr(err)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://us.battle.net/oauth/token", &form)
    checkErr(err)
    req.SetBasicAuth(id, secret)
    resp, err := cli.Do(req)
    checkErr(err)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    json := make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err = resp.Body.Read(json)
    checkErr(err)
    return string(json)
}

func main() {
    //un(trace("main"))
    const apiID string = "user"
    const apiSecret string = "password"
    apiClient := &http.Client{}
    auth := authcode(apiID, apiSecret, *apiClient)
    fmt.Printf("%s", auth)
}
```

When I run this I get a response of `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"}`

For reference, the api flow states:
"To request access tokens, an application must make a POST request with the following multipart form data to the token URI: grant_type=client_credentials

The application must pass basic HTTP auth credentials using the client_id as the user and client_secret as the password."
and the expected response is a json string containing an access token, token type, expiration in seconds, and the scope of functions available with said token

Comment: The curl command indicates that the documentation is wrong when it mentions a multipart request. Try as the request body `strings.NewReader("grant_type=client_credentials")` (for anything more complicated use [url.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) though, which handles escaping properly). In any case, you are calling CreateFormField wrong: the argument is just the field name, not name and value.

Comment: @peter I tried that and still got the invalid request error

Comment: You may have to set the Content-Type header also: `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately

Comment: Never mind this worked, I had made a typo changing the code so the id was off. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From curl manual we have:

```
       -d, --data <data>
          (HTTP)  Sends  the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and
          presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.   Compare  to
          -F, --form.
```

Note the `content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded` part.

as opposed to:

```
       -F, --form <name=content>
          (HTTP SMTP IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl  to
          POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.
```

Therefore based on your `curl`, `mime/multipart` is probably not what you're looking for and you should be using [`Client.PostForm`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.PostForm), from the manual of which we have:

```
The Content-Type header is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. To set other headers, use NewRequest and Client.Do.
```

Comment: Will PostForm allow me to still use the 'SetBasicAuth(id, secret)' part or will I need to do something else? I tried the other response and added 'strings.NewReader("grant_type=client_credentials")' as the body and it still gave me the invalid request